# Compiling a DLL in C++ mingw 64

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll, mingw-w64

I want to compile a DLL in C++ and then call the Library from VBA. I have done this on windows32 bits. But I wanted to replicate such exercise since I use Windows 64 bit at work. Given this fact I downdloaded mingw 64.

My example:

main.h

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
int DLL_EXPORT __stdcall add2(int num);
int DLL_EXPORT __stdcall mult(int num1, int num2);
}

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

int DLL_EXPORT __stdcall add2(int num)
{
return num + 2;
}


int DLL_EXPORT __stdcall mult(int num1, int num2)
 {
 int product;
 product = num1 * num2;
 return product;
 }
```

When I compile the dll I pass this linker options:

```
Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```

and/or

```
Wl,--kill-at
```

I also generate the .def file, which looks like this:

```
EXPORTS
   add2 @1
   mult @2
```

I expected a .def file which looks like this (as in my 32bit PC):

```
EXPORTS
   add2 @1
   mult @2
   add2 = add2 @1
   mult = mult @2
```

Then I call the dll and the functions from VBA like this:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function add2 _
Lib "C:\MyPath\dll.dll" _
(ByVal num As Long) As Long
```

The problem is: The functions can be called from VBA editor and gives right results, but when called from an Excel sheet they throw some other number (address of the passed argument??). If I try to call the function from VBA AFTER I tried inside Excel, then VBA throws an error (out of stack Space).

This problem is not present when I use mingw4.7 32bit. The problem is when I compile using mingw 4.6.3 64bit (I had installed mingw4.7 64bit but I found on internet People saying that 4.6.3 is more stable)

I have also noticed that the .def file looks identicall to the one above even if i dont pass my linker options.

Can anybody help? whats happening? is mingw64 or vba/Excel feiling? or is my mingw64 configuration?

**UPDATE**....
ok I found this site :https://sites.google.com/site/jrlhost/links/excelcdll#array and as explain there by using and itermediate function in VBA, my function add2 Works from the worksheet.

```
Public function fromWorksheetAdd2 ( dim x as Long) as Long
   fromWorksheetAdd2 = add2(x)
end function
```

then I can use fromWorksheetAdd2 at worksheets and Add2 at VBA. However this approach is kind of tedious. Hope someone can help With an elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your parameters.

A Long in VBA is 64 bits (8 bytes).  On the C++ side, the size of an int is whatever sizeof(int) is, which is more than likely 4 bytes in the environment you're using.

You must guarantee that the types you're sending and returning between VBA and C++ are exactly the same size, otherwise you can wind up with stack corruption.

Comment: When you create DLL's from C or C++ to be used by other languages, it is preferred that you use the Windows API defined types such as LONG, DWORD, as parameters or return types in your exported functions instead of the C++ int, long, etc.  This way, you don't get into the mess of having types not match up.

Comment: I have tried to used long long variables in C++ and VBA both should by 8 bytes. I also used LONG in C++ and Long in VBA. But none of these approaches fixed my problem. I am still wondering on the effect of Wl,--add-stdcall-alias